# Objective-C - Text baseline on lower left corner

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, position, baseline

When drawing a string in IOS, by default the text is baselined by the upper left corner. This can cause problems when using **multiple** strings with different font-sizes with the same y-coordinate.

**Question;**

How do I **baseline** a string by the **lower left corner of the first row**.

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem.
By subtracting the **UIFont ascender** property from the rect.origin.y, I could baseline the text to the lower left corner.

Citing the UIFont documentation of the ascender property:

> "The top y-coordinate, offset from the baseline, of the receiver’s longest ascender."
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIFont/ascender

```
- (void)drawTextBaseLined:(NSString *)text
                     rect:(CGRect)rect
                     font:(UIFont *)font
{
  if ([text length] == 0) return false;

  NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : font};

  rect.origin.y -= font.ascender;
  [text drawWithRect:rect
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
          attributes:attributes
             context:nil];
}
```

This method will work with one or multiple lines of text and with different font-sizes.
I hope my solution helps someone else too.

Br,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;`

When you have the height of your label just do the math to choose the right origin of it to have the below left corner always at the same place.

```
NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFont]};

CGRect rect = [[NSString string] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
```

If you want your label below left corner to be always at 50pix the origin of your label will be at (50 - rect.size.height).

Change the size to adapt to your constraints.

Comment: What do i do with the result? I don't know how to offset the text vertically so it baselines on the exact lower left corner of the first row.

Comment: Complete code snippet would be appreciated. =) I don't know which options or attributes that needs to be set for the function.

Comment: The value returned by your function returns different results for different font-sizes.

Example:

Text1 font size 12 at x = 200, y = 400,  will yield a height of 14.316
Text2 font size 18 at x = 200, y = 400  will yield a height of 21.73999
Subtracting this value from the y-coordinate for text1 and text2 position the bigger font (text2) higher up than the smaller font (400-14.316 vs 400-21.73999). I want the bottom left corner both text1 and text2 to be positioned at exactly y = 400.

Comment: This function doesn't change your label size. Don't forget to call sizeToFit to make sure it does have the size that will make it work. Or to be very sure assign the frame yourself with the rect the method gives you, and of course change the origin after.

Comment: Could you give a code exampel of how baseline one multi-line text with font-size 12 and one multi-line text with fonts-size 18? Please refer to the updated image for a more clear illustration of my problem.

I am using NSString currently, are there any pros of using labels instead?